# Add arrow heads on Google Line Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I've been working on a Google Line chart project

```
oChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('main'));

drawChart();
setInterval(drawChart, 800);

var rowIndex = 0;

function drawChart() {
    if (rowIndex < oRawData.length) {
        data.addRow(oRawData[rowIndex++]);
        oChart.draw(data, oAltered);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add an arrow head when you call the draw() function in google chart? I can't seem to any in its documentation.

Comment: nothing provided out of the box, closest would be [changing the last point to a triangle](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points#rotations) -- you could also use an [image overlay](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays#positioning-overlaysrelative-to-data) -- however, the hardest part with either option would be getting the arrow pointing in the right direction / angle...